# Need help setting up a java project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I need some help in setting up a Java project in eclipse 3.7.1. My project uses the Java files I create and two jar files from an open source project.

One of the jar files, call it compiler.jar, converts a text file, my.txt, into a .java file. In order to create this Java file, the compiler.jar needs access to the class files that I create for the project.

The other jar file, runtime.jar, contains classes that are needed to create the final run time project. This jar file gets compiled in with the java files I write and the Java file created by the compiler.jar.

Outside of eclipse, I have all the java files and the two jar files in one directory. These are the steps I follow to create my run time project:

```
1. Create/edit my Java files. Create/edit my.txt for compiler.jar.
2. javac -cp .:runtime.jar *.java               // To create class files for next step
3. java -cp .:compiler.jar CompilerMain my.txt  // This creates my.java
4. javac -cp .:runtime.jar *.java
5. java -cp .:runtime.jar MyProjectMain
```

What is the best way to set up this project in Eclipse?

How do I run step 3 in eclipse?

Where is the best place to put my.txt - in with the Java source files? It's own directory in the source tree?

My goal is to create a jar file with all the classes and does not contain my.txt, so I can use this jar file in other projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up 2 Java projects.

The first project will use the compiler.jar and build the class files from the text file.

In order to execute the compiler jar, you'll need to set up an Eclipse Run Configuration for compiler.jar.  I'm assuming compiler.jar is a Java Application.

After running compiler.jar, you package the compiled class files into a jar.  You can have Eclipse do this as an Export, or you can create an Ant script that will package the compiled class files.

The second project will create the runtime.jar.  This project will point to the compiler class files or the jar file from the first project as an external reference in the Java Build Path of this project.

Comment: After some experimenting, I found it was easiest to just create one project, and two packages. One package for the Java files I write, and one package for the text file that is parsed into a Java file. I could not get the two project solution to work (but I gave up after several attempts, so I am not saying it is impossible to get two projects to work in this scenario.) I also added a third package for JUnit tests, and it all seems to be working now. Thanks, Gilbert, for your suggestions.